# Spring Boot : No me aparece el decorador @Email para validar correos, entre algunos otros que no me aparecen, alguna solución?

Tags: api, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

**Spring Boot** : No me aparece el decorador @Email para validar correos, entre algunos otros como el @NotEmpty, etc etc, alguna solución?

Answer (score 2):

A partir de cierta versión no están incluidos, prueba a introducir en el pom esto

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```